# @Injectable compared to plain old static methods

Tags: angular

I have a utility class that converts one object to another and vice versa.

```
export class Converter {
   public toFoo(bar: Bar) : Foo {}
   public toBar(foo: Foo) : Bar {}
}
```

Would it be better to make this class @Injectable?

```
@Injectable
export class Converter {
   public toFoo(bar: Bar) : Foo {}
   public toBar(foo: Foo) : Bar {}
}
```

Or is the static method be better in this case?

```
export class Converter {
   static toFoo(bar: Bar) : Foo {}
   static toBar(foo: Foo) : Bar {}
}
```

Comment: ّInjectable marks it as a service, Therefore it will be shared across the application and will be singleton

Comment: Will you ever have to mock or spy on the converter's methods in unit tests? Is there a chance the conversion logic ever needs another angular service to do its job? That's what drives the choice between an injectable service and a plain old function.

Comment: Based on the current implementation, there won't be a need to import another angular service. But based on what I gather, @Injectable approach is more flexible since you can easily inject  dependencies if you need it. Is there any advantage on using plain old static methods?